# Fisher test interpretation for left or right sided p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, interpretation

Let say I have a frequency table of two variables $x$ and $y$ having or not having some property.

$$ \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{} & x & y \\
\mbox{has property} & 20 & 2 \\
\mbox{does not have property} & 61 & 79 \end{array}\
$$

What does it really mean to have positive (right hand side p-value) or negative (left-hand side p-value) association. Can I think of it as of correlation between variables $x$ and $y$? Why then for table

$$ \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{} & x & x \\
\mbox{has property} & 20 & 20 \\
\mbox{does not have property} & 61 & 61 \end{array}\
$$

I get large p-value not rejecting the null hypothesis?

EDIT: Null hypothesis states that variables are independent, that is the proportions do not differ among $x$,$y$ vs. has/does not have property. The right / left p-value regards associations on the diagonals of the tables [like here](http://www.langsrud.com/stat/fisher.htm)

Comment: Please explain on what you mean by "right hand side" and "left-hand side" p-values.  In your second question, tell us specifically what the "null hypothesis" says.

Comment: @whuber Post was edited.

Answer (score 1):

The error is to believe that you can analyze two 'variables' having only one observation of each. 
What you have is two levels for a qualitative variable and two levels for the other. You cannot observe variation on that situation. 
In this case you can try a Chi square test and after that, try to explain the level of correlation (if exists) with Cramer or any other measure of relationship.